How to use Dot product on different levels
Given
t2 = {{{1, 6, {{x -> 3, y -> 7}, {x -> 5, y -> 9}}}, {1, 4, {{x -> 2, y -> 3}}}}, {{2, 8, {{x -> 7, y -> 3}}}, {2, 3, {{x -> 2, y -> 4}, {x -> 9, y -> 2}}}}}

I want to use Dot (or whatever) so that I get
{{{1*3 + 6*7}, {{1*5 + 6*9}}}, {{1*2 + 4*3}}, {{2*7 + 8*3}}, {{2*2 + 3*4}, {2*9 + 3*2}}}

I cant work through the different levels.

BlockMap[({#[[1 ;; 2]] . {x, y}} /. #[[3]] &), Level[t2, {3}], 3]

(* {{{45}, {59}}, {{14}}, {{38}}, {{16}, {24}}} *)


Also BlockMap[({Most[#] . {x, y}} /. Last[#] &), Level[t2, {3}], 3]


{1 * 3 + 6 * 7}

Is this supposed to be multiplication? i.e. you want {3+42} or {45} as result?
if so, one way is to first remove all the rules to simplify t2 then Map Inner:
     Inner[Times, {x[[1]], x[[2]]}, #, Plus]

On the rest of each list.
Like this
t2 = {{{1, 6, {{x -> 3, y -> 7}, {x -> 5, y -> 9}}}, {1, 
    4, {{x -> 2, y -> 3}}}}, {{2, 8, {{x -> 7, y -> 3}}}, {2, 
    3, {{x -> 2, y -> 4}, {x -> 9, y -> 2}}}}}
t3 = t2 /. Rule[a_, b_] :> b

(*{{{1, 6, {{3, 7}, {5, 9}}}, {1, 4, {{2, 3}}}}, {{2, 8, {{7, 3}}}, {2, 
   3, {{2, 4}, {9, 2}}}}}*)

And now
f[x_List] := Map[{Inner[Times, {x[[1]], x[[2]]}, #, Plus]} &, x[[3]]]
Map[f[#] &, t3, {2}]

(* {{{{45}, {59}}, {{14}}}, {{{38}}, {{16}, {24}}}} *)

If you do not want the extra {} I add in Map, then do
f[x_List] := Map[Inner[Times, {x[[1]], x[[2]]}, #, Plus] &, x[[3]]]
Map[f[#] &, t3, {2}]

(*  {{{45, 59}, {14}}, {{38}, {16, 24}}} *)

If you have to keep the multiplication in there, you can use Inactive, like this
f[x_List] := Map[{Inner[Inactive[Times], {x[[1]], x[[2]]}, #, Plus]} &, x[[3]]]
Map[f[#] &, t3, {2}]


Again, if you do not want the extra {} in there, remove the {} from the above Map command
f[x_List] := Map[Inner[Inactive[Times], {x[[1]], x[[2]]}, #, Plus] &, x[[3]]]
Map[f[#] &, t3, {2}]


I am sure there are many more ways to do this in Mathematica.

Wow! The function f[x_List] was the thing I was looking for. Great! Thanks!

Using Replace and ArrayDepth:
Replace[t2, {a__, m_?MatrixQ} :> Thread@List@Values[m] . {a}, {ArrayDepth@t2 - 1}]


{{{{45}, {59}}, {{14}}}, {{{38}}, {{16}, {24}}}}

Or without extra {}:
Replace[t2, {a__, m_?MatrixQ} :> Values[m] . {a}, {ArrayDepth@t2 - 1}]


{{{45, 59}, {14}}, {{38}, {16, 24}}}

The Inactive case:
Replace[t2, {a__, m_?MatrixQ} :> 
Map[List@Inner[Inactive[Times], {a}, #, Inactive[Plus]] &, 
Values[m]], {ArrayDepth@t2 - 1}]


Or without extra {}:
Replace[t2, {a__, m_?MatrixQ} :> 
Map[Inner[Inactive[Times], {a}, #, Inactive[Plus]] &, 
Values[m]], {ArrayDepth@t2 - 1}]


Edit: To separate the two resulting arrays, we simply use Flatten as follows:
Flatten[Replace[
t2, {a__, m_?MatrixQ} :> 
Thread@List@Values[m] . {a}, {ArrayDepth@t2 - 1}], 1]


{{{45}, {59}}, {{14}}, {{38}}, {{16}, {24}}}


Using:
t2 = {{{1, 6, {{x -> 3, y -> 7}, {x -> 5, y -> 9}}}, {1, 
    4, {{x -> 2, y -> 3}}}}, {{2, 8, {{x -> 7, y -> 3}}}, {2, 
    3, {{x -> 2, y -> 4}, {x -> 9, y -> 2}}}}}

MapAt can be applied:
f[{x_, y_, a_}] := {x, y} . # & /@ a
MapAt[f, MapAt[{x, y} /. # &, t2, {All, All, 3}], {All, All}]

yields:
 {{{45, 59}, {14}}, {{38}, {16, 24}}}


t2 = {{{1, 6, {{x -> 3, y -> 7}, {x -> 5, y -> 9}}}, {1, 
    4, {{x -> 2, y -> 3}}}}, {{2, 8, {{x -> 7, y -> 3}}}, {2, 
    3, {{x -> 2, y -> 4}, {x -> 9, y -> 2}}}}}

Cases[t2, {k : __Integer, h : _List} :> 
  Dot @@ {{k}, Transpose[{x, y} /. h]}, All]



{{45, 59}, {14}, {38}, {16, 24}}


In the interest of getting to 10...
Map[Thread, t2, {2}] /. {x1_, y1_, {_ -> x2_, _ -> y2_}} :> {x1, y1} . {x2, y2}


Here's a ridiculous one-liner:
t2 = {{{1, 6, {{x -> 3, y -> 7}, {x -> 5, y -> 9}}}, {1, 4, {{x -> 2, y -> 3}}}}, 
      {{2, 8, {{x -> 7, y -> 3}}}, {2, 3, {{x -> 2, y -> 4}, {x -> 9, y -> 2}}}}};

Map[Map[Apply[Dot]@ArrayReshape[#, {2, 2}] &]@*Thread, t2 /. (_ -> v_) :> v, {2}]

(* {{{45, 59}, {14}}, {{38}, {16, 24}}} *)

This isn't the exact same structure as your expected output, but I think your expected output doesn't actually match the structure of t2, so this is my best guess as to what you want.

You just cracked my brain!
